# Using Retrofit with Imgur's API

Tags: java, image, api, retrofit, imgur

I'm attempting to use the Retrofit library with Imgur's API with no success. I keep receiving 403 Permission Denied errors. The only authorization Imgur uses for what I'm attempting to do is through a header, which I (believe) I am doing correctly. My current code is the following:

---

```
package me.rabrg.imgur;

import me.rabrg.imgur.response.Image;
import me.rabrg.imgur.service.ImageService;
import retrofit.RequestInterceptor;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;

public class ImgurApi {

    private final RestAdapter restAdapter;
    private final ImageService imageService;

    public ImgurApi(final String clientId) {
        this.restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint("https://api.imgur.com/3").setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
            @Override
            public void intercept(final RequestFacade request) {
                request.addHeader("Authorization", "Client-ID " + clientId);
            }
        }).build();

        this.imageService = restAdapter.create(ImageService.class);
    }

    public Image getImage(final String id) {
        return imageService.getImage(id);
    }
}
```

---

```
package me.rabrg.imgur.service;

import me.rabrg.imgur.response.Image;
import retrofit.http.POST;
import retrofit.http.Path;

public interface ImageService {

    @POST("/image/{id}")
    Image getImage(@Path("id") String id);
}
```

---

```
new ImgurApi(clientId).getImage(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Haha, silly me...

The method `getImage` had the annotation `@POST("/image/{id}")` instead of `@GET("/image/{id}")`

Comment: it Happens some times ,Anyways I have simmilar problem , all code is fine ,I dont not why there is error , in callback please can you check my code and help solve proble : https://github.com/geniushkg/Android-Retrofit-callback-async-sample  ,compile and run , you'l come to know , I have added log statement , my callback executes failure , why i dont know

Comment: Haha silly me, for got permision to use internet ,but still one error ,Econnection refused