# Using Retrofit with the Imgur API

Tags: java, android, retrofit

After checking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800515/using-retrofit-with-imgurs-api) and a [Vogella tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html#retrofit) I can't seem to figure out how to use `Retrofit` with the [Imgur API](https://api.imgur.com/).

Here is what I do so far:

```
public class APIHandler implements Callback<List<ImageData>> {

    static final String BASE_URL = "https://api.imgur.com/";

    public void start() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        ImgurAPI imgur = retrofit.create(ImgurAPI.class);

        Call<List<ImageData>> call = imgur.getGallery("0");
        call.enqueue(this);

    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<ImageData>> call, Response<List<ImageData>> response) {
        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
            List<ImageData> picturesList = response.body();
            picturesList.forEach(picture -> System.out.println(picture.getTitle()));
        } else {
            System.out.println(response.errorBody());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<ImageData>> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my interface:

```
public interface ImgurAPI {
    @GET("/3/gallery/hot/viral/{page}")
    Call<List<ImageData>> getGallery(@Path("page") String page);
}
```

I am trying to display a `JSON` array containing the trending pictures, but where I try to call my `start` method `call.enqueue(this)` gives me the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Which I find odd considering `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/image/{id}` returns an array.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

As Selvin has noted I have misread the documentation, it should return a single object, therefore I have changed the type returned to a simple `ImageData` - the request is successful, but when I try to read the data like such, it is null:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<ImageData> call, Response<ImageData> response) {
    if(response.isSuccessful()) {
        ImageData image = response.body();
        System.out.println(image.getTitle());
    } else {
        System.out.println(response.errorBody());
    }
}
```

Comment: what's is the actual response you're getting from the API? it can be error response which is indeed not an array and hence the parse cannot parse the result

Comment: *Which I find odd considering `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/image/{id}` returns an array. What am I doing wrong?* **your consideration is wrong** [documentation states clear that it is a single image](https://api.imgur.com/models/gallery_image)

Comment: @yosriz: How may I retrieve the response? My `Callback`'s `onFailure` catches the error I have shared.

@Selvin: Understood, I will change a few things and come back to this question in order to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: @Christopher, what the url you're consuming? if it's `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/hot/viral/0` it sure returns a Json Object.

Comment: @Christopher, as were said please verify that you expect the right response from the endpoint, besides that, **onError** will not catch error responses, Retrofit just will not throw it, but will try to parse the error response